# cpr javascript parent frame reference fail with Edge & FF but worked with now deprecated IE

Tags: javascript

cpr javascript parent frame reference fail with Edge & FF but worked with IE

For the new browsers, the
parent.frames[1].document
can not be accessed by the index.html

I believe even parent.frames[1] fails the same

The actual error is

index.html:330

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

This code is fails and is directly after the global var's in index.html

// Code that picks up frame names of frames in the parent frameset.            *

var MTMFrameNames = new Array();

for(i = 0; i < parent.frames.length; i++) {

MTMFrameNames[i] = parent.frames[i].name;

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Some changes for the DOM frame / window // document referencing causes parent.frames[1]  to nolonger resolve, thus null DOMException see above. Maybe parent.frames is no longer supported ? Code did not change but failed for current FF & Edge browsers